Can't escape the single quote of sed command in a groovy pipeline
I am a beginner with Jenkins/Groovy Pipeline.

I have to clean some logs after running a script, for that I use the
bash command:

sed -e $'s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*m//g' -e 's/[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{6\} [a-zA-Z]* *: //' file1.log > file2.log

I adapt it to the groovy pipeline by escaping the $ and \ :

sh "sed -e \$'s/\\033[[][^A-Za-z]*m//g' -e 's/[0-9]\\{2\\}:[0-9]\\{2\\}:[0-9]\\{2\\}\\.[0-9]\\{6\\} [a-zA-Z]* *: //' file1.log > file2.log"
But I systematically get, in the log output, a bash command without single quote :
sed -e $s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*m//g -e s/[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{6\} [a-zA-Z]* *: // 
I tried to escape the single quotes with \ or enclose the command with " or """" without success. The single quotes vanished into oblivion.
The other Stack Overflow exchange about this problem doesn't bring any solution in my case (or I failed to reproduce).
I am using Jenkins 2.414.2
The question is how can I run this sed command into my pipeline ?

Maybe this helps: Jenkinsfile idiosynchrasies with escaping and quotes
